# Timestamp with time zone offset

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, timestamp, timezone

The goal is to get current local timestamp in specific format with added time zone offset. E.g.:

```
2023-08-28T03:51:46.222+09:30
```

I cannot find a Spark function which would return time zone offset *with colon* `:`

So far I have this - the offset is incorrect and it misses the colon:

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

df.select(F.date_format(F.from_utc_timestamp(F.current_timestamp(), 'Australia/Adelaide'), "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ")).show(1, truncate=0)
# +----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
# |date_format(from_utc_timestamp(current_timestamp(), Australia/Adelaide), yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ)|
# +----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
# |2023-08-28T22:53:42.651+0000                                                                        |
# +----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

I use Spark 3.2.

Comment: Per online doc https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.2.0/sql-ref-datetime-pattern.html : 
_Offset X and x: This formats the offset based on the number of pattern letters...._

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First get the timestamp in current timezone using `current_timestamp` then, use `date_format` with the special format specifier `xxx` which outputs the hour and minute offset seperated with a colon

```
fmt = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSxxx"
df.select(F.date_format(F.current_timestamp(), fmt))
```

---

```
+--------------------------------------------------------------+
|date_format(current_timestamp(), yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSxxx)|
+--------------------------------------------------------------+
|2023-08-28T19:54:08.624+05:30                                 |
+--------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: I cannot reproduce the successful result neither in my system, nor in Google Colab. My system (Palantir Foundry) returns `pyspark.sql.utils.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal pattern character 'x'`, while Google Colab returns `+00:00` as ending, no matter if I use current timezone or change it with from_utc_timestamp

Comment: @ZygD The output of `date_format` function depends on the value of the current timezone configuration specified using `spark.sql.session.timeZone` setting. I guess in google colab the default value for timezone is `UTC`

Comment: Personally, I have tested the above code in `pyspark==3.4` but nevertheless I can also check in version `3.2` to see if I can reproduce the error message

Comment: This makes sense. `x` is not recognized probably because of my system. They did some changes regarding datetime... In Colab, I specifically used version 3.2, so `x` is well recognized in this version.